# Using asp:dropdownlist OR asp:radioButtonList to emulate BootStrap 3 Select

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap-3, webforms

My code is below

```
<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
  20 <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
  <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server">
      <asp:ListItem class="DropDownRadioButtonList">Item 1</asp:ListItem>
      <asp:ListItem class="DropDownRadioButtonList">Item 2</asp:ListItem>
      <asp:ListItem class="DropDownRadioButtonList">Item 3</asp:ListItem>
      <asp:ListItem class="DropDownRadioButtonList">Item 4</asp:ListItem>
  </asp:RadioButtonList>
</ul>
</div>
```

What I'm trying to do is emulate the appearance of the Select box on the right in the image below.  My code produces the Select in the Image on the LEFT

[image]

Comment: Not clear what you are asking?
Are you asking for someone to write the code for the drop down "Sort By" and if so what is it's function(s)

Comment: I'm attempting to use either a radiobutton list OR a dropdownlist with BootStrap 3.  The code I wrote above achieves the result on the left..I'm hoping someone can point me to what mistake I'm making or an example that would **look** closer to that on the right.

Comment: unclear: do you need just the one or both selectors?

Comment: I will only use one.  The one on the right is an example of pure HTML input that looks correct.  The example on the left is what I've attempted to sar and  its visual output.

Answer (score 0):

try adding class to RadioButtonList.